# Does Angular.JS add CSS styles or changes existing styles?

Tags: angularjs

This is a weird one we're currently porting an existing CakePHP app to Angular.JS, the CSS is the same and overall everything looks the same but there is small changes for example the font type or the size, also noticing small difference in spacing, padding and margins.

Does Angular add CSS style or overwrite existing styles?

Comment: are you using any other JS frameworks other than AngularJS such as AngularUI or JqueryUI?

Comment: No not at this point, it's very weird

Answer (score 2):

AngularJS does not add any style elements nor does it add or remove any inline styles. It does however add classes to DOM elements such as ng-scope, ng-binding..etc all with the "ng" prefix.

Comment: Thank that shouldn't affect things. Might do a print screen

Answer (score 1):

Angular does add a few CSS styles, but nothing that would account for what you're seeing.

In particular, to hide elements while they're loading through an ngCloak directive, Angular adds a class to set the display property to 'none'.

You can see Angular's CSS in https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/css/angular.css.

Comment: Thanks, still haven't figured it out